# Use chlorophyll a Galvanic cell to create hydrogen and electricity

Tags: photochemistry

What if we want to take chlorophyll in a container and put it into light . Then chlorophyll will lose electrons and will become positive itself then we will have a solution of negatively flowing electrons and positively charged chlorophyll molecules.

But somehow we have to lose electrons and transfer them somewhere so what we can do is take a Galvanic cell and directly  place a wire between the solution and copper rod . Then maybe electrons can get transfer from chlorophyll solution to Galvanic cell and the Salt Bridge between Copper and zinc rods neutralize the solution .

Then once the chlorophyll becomes completely positively charged and electrons have transferred we will put water into it then the electrons from H2O will be gained from chlorophyll molecules and H2 will get separated into h+ two molecules and one molecule of o . Two molecules will form oxygen and get released into the air while h+ and will remain in the solution.

Then we will take another container with chlorophyll that has been put into the light and we will connect wire between these two chlorophyll solutions and electron from the the second container will flow to the first container and H + ions will get converted to H2 gas and we will capture this gas and will use all the electricity flowing between.

Will this method work?

Comment: Technical note: Sentences in scientific context are recommended to have 20-25 words in average, with recommendation not to cross the word limit 35. Additionally, elementary thoughts are recommended to put into separated paragraphs to make reading easier. Your post has 2 sentences, the first one quite giant, the 2nd one has 4 words. It is very difficult to follow for these formal reasons. It would be even worse in case of a speech.

Comment: Sorry,  I edited question to make it easier to read.  Please remove negative marking.

Comment: Try to create more than 1 paragraph. Divide the idea into several sub-ideas. You will see how easier it would be to read it.  It is very small effort and it helps readers a lot. For a test, grab any unknown multiparagraph text  and merge it into a single paragraph. Then read it. :-)

Comment: I have done it. Thanks for recommendation.

Comment: Good. But from chemistry point of view, it is much more complicated. There are no free electrons in the solution, but thay are bound to other organic molecules. But yes, there already is the shortcut to generate electricity, instead of glucose creation.

Comment: So there must also be a way to get h2 gas. And electricity.Please tell me the method.

Comment: The site policy supposes the user asking a question does his figural homework first, doing the basic research for the topic. Then coming only when he/she got stuck, providing info what he/she has already done. Perceived low effort at the user side may be considered as the reason for closing the question. The effort of the one who asks should not be highly disbalanced with the expected/requested effort of those who answers. That makes the SE sites unique with high quality answers AND questions.

Comment: Just beware that water splitting by the sun is ongoing research. Whatever you use as photosctivated species the concept is that. It might be TiO2, etc.I think you could search for something like "green or solar water splitting" etc...